# VectorColorFunction not working at a few points

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, vector

I use the following data to `ListVectorPlot` a vector field with the color indicating the vector direction. However, there seem to be some vectors not colored properly (gray instead). Anything I did wrong or any workaround?

[image]

```
data={{{{-0.9`,-0.9`},{-0.6866908336723556`,0.726949584875296`}},{{-0.9`,-0.753061224489796`},{-0.6930302969226753`,0.7209084598943675`}},{{-0.9`,-0.6061224489795919`},{-0.8185220301466313`,0.5744751397272447`}},{{-0.9`,-0.4591836734693878`},{-0.958498237160233`,0.28509845555654223`}},{{-0.9`,-0.31224489795918375`},{-0.9746860210105036`,0.22357808579266425`}},{{-0.9`,-0.1653061224489797`},{-0.9048821302576031`,0.42566222564430384`}},{{-0.9`,-0.01836734693877562`},{-0.7107525946370554`,0.7034420723959389`}},{{-0.9`,0.12857142857142845`},{-0.41198384495090146`,0.9111911498140616`}},{{-0.9`,0.2755102040816325`},{-0.08477882260846661`,0.9963997948801084`}},{{-0.9`,0.4224489795918366`},{0.20632603068225291`,0.9784833003495288`}},{{-0.9`,0.5693877551020406`},{0.4314782259529821`,0.9021233510604119`}},{{-0.9`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.5879448440973385`,0.8089010200879686`}},{{-0.9`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.6880784743525821`,0.7256362815713002`}}},{{{-0.753061224489796`,-0.9`},{-0.8117282071229162`,0.5840353737240717`}},{{-0.753061224489796`,-0.753061224489796`},{-0.9994447453898445`,-0.03331967755890003`}},{{-0.753061224489796`,-0.6061224489795919`},{-0.5249863300836353`,-0.851110658625138`}},{{-0.753061224489796`,-0.4591836734693878`},{-0.538408781081774`,-0.8426837986184607`}},{{-0.753061224489796`,-0.31224489795918375`},{-0.7649098594696535`,-0.6441373354232113`}},{{-0.753061224489796`,-0.1653061224489797`},{-0.9709379052316043`,-0.23933153612606958`}},{{-0.753061224489796`,-0.01836734693877562`},{-0.9572960321446599`,0.289109506658101`}},{{-0.753061224489796`,0.12857142857142845`},{-0.6783223610314336`,0.7347644347168291`}},{{-0.753061224489796`,0.2755102040816325`},{-0.2708196304399401`,0.9626301095272131`}},{{-0.753061224489796`,0.4224489795918366`},{0.11033624021303726`,0.9938943173676218`}},{{-0.753061224489796`,0.5693877551020406`},{0.40351657198882757`,0.9149723362650838`}},{{-0.753061224489796`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.6043324948965484`,0.796732223279637`}},{{-0.753061224489796`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.728649490163984`,0.6848867939183572`}}},{{{-0.6061224489795919`,-0.9`},{-0.9249501882476456`,-0.380088344021025`}},{{-0.6061224489795919`,-0.753061224489796`},{0.22519378630383785`,-0.9743139938490782`}},{{-0.6061224489795919`,-0.6061224489795919`},{0.15620698558034687`,-0.9877243429499455`}},{{-0.6061224489795919`,-0.4591836734693878`},{-0.09797587145998544`,-0.9951887904370991`}},{{-0.6061224489795919`,-0.31224489795918375`},{-0.5265805603128018`,-0.8501252340100579`}},{{-0.6061224489795919`,-0.1653061224489797`},{-0.9314270846118379`,-0.3639279956962535`}},{{-0.6061224489795919`,-0.01836734693877562`},{-0.995002118761485`,0.09985381144531076`}},{{-0.6061224489795919`,0.12857142857142845`},{-0.8592460414334341`,0.5115625477700388`}},{{-0.6061224489795919`,0.2755102040816325`},{-0.38622030405632873`,0.922406568024446`}},{{-0.6061224489795919`,0.4224489795918366`},{0.10492720915857859`,0.9944799046628303`}},{{-0.6061224489795919`,0.5693877551020406`},{0.43086793650875094`,0.9024149939405323`}},{{-0.6061224489795919`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.6431635582229297`,0.7657288275714975`}},{{-0.6061224489795919`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.7742565984069888`,0.6328718036247459`}}},{{{-0.4591836734693878`,-0.9`},{0.6083750445631247`,-0.7936496740708813`}},{{-0.4591836734693878`,-0.753061224489796`},{0.5997462087872881`,-0.8001902805241229`}},{{-0.4591836734693878`,-0.6061224489795919`},{0.46135122424648767`,-0.8872175876786184`}},{{-0.4591836734693878`,-0.4591836734693878`},{0.0679005102080521`,-0.997692097148958`}},{{-0.4591836734693878`,-0.31224489795918375`},{-0.9751196995293712`,0.22167898319360135`}},{{-0.4591836734693878`,-0.1653061224489797`},{-0.5279247064507885`,0.8492911775821346`}},{{-0.4591836734693878`,-0.01836734693877562`},{-0.28489882198405214`,0.958557594113207`}},{{-0.4591836734693878`,0.12857142857142845`},{-0.44890799795494074`,-0.8935779816961065`}},{{-0.4591836734693878`,0.2755102040816325`},{-0.8870893315127719`,-0.4615977880322039`}},{{-0.4591836734693878`,0.4224489795918366`},{0.041311316460336665`,0.9991463231841038`}},{{-0.4591836734693878`,0.5693877551020406`},{0.5390685450176083`,0.8422618973767001`}},{{-0.4591836734693878`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.7262153301995322`,0.6874673040830265`}},{{-0.4591836734693878`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.8352887793476351`,0.5498114723211381`}}},{{{-0.31224489795918375`,-0.9`},{0.8453414133937096`,-0.5342264452472614`}},{{-0.31224489795918375`,-0.753061224489796`},{0.804422778104649`,-0.5940572313055357`}},{{-0.31224489795918375`,-0.6061224489795919`},{0.6870235372840334`,-0.7266351623873801`}},{{-0.31224489795918375`,-0.4591836734693878`},{-0.9983592275337331`,0.0572612678714664`}},{{-0.31224489795918375`,-0.31224489795918375`},{-0.6858118094006856`,0.7277789239092854`}},{{-0.31224489795918375`,-0.1653061224489797`},{0.7809387602278167`,0.6246075990362594`}},{{-0.31224489795918375`,-0.01836734693877562`},{0.9977115714446826`,0.067613757515627`}},{{-0.31224489795918375`,0.12857142857142845`},{0.9756613591489007`,-0.2192827222188732`}},{{-0.31224489795918375`,0.2755102040816325`},{-0.539426065793158`,-0.8420329682042833`}},{{-0.31224489795918375`,0.4224489795918366`},{-0.9201707255647014`,-0.391517350590917`}},{{-0.31224489795918375`,0.5693877551020406`},{0.6836242970540718`,0.7298341047644501`}},{{-0.31224489795918375`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.8412964722432803`,0.5405739965915968`}},{{-0.31224489795918375`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.9076249446288942`,0.4197820385478597`}}},{{{-0.1653061224489797`,-0.9`},{0.9565015896333602`,-0.29172711397615236`}},{{-0.1653061224489797`,-0.753061224489796`},{0.9408570470085357`,-0.3388038032466254`}},{{-0.1653061224489797`,-0.6061224489795919`},{0.867542932732215`,-0.49736230241785273`}},{{-0.1653061224489797`,-0.4591836734693878`},{-0.9543497109862151`,0.29869152840435165`}},{{-0.1653061224489797`,-0.31224489795918375`},{0.2944515164147587`,0.9556664190401635`}},{{-0.1653061224489797`,-0.1653061224489797`},{0.9991082381805628`,-0.042222368476103084`}},{{-0.1653061224489797`,-0.01836734693877562`},{0.999891899668547`,0.01470336618684117`}},{{-0.1653061224489797`,0.12857142857142845`},{0.9963338625091069`,0.0855501865438286`}},{{-0.1653061224489797`,0.2755102040816325`},{0.9912177965512312`,-0.1322394789770513`}},{{-0.1653061224489797`,0.4224489795918366`},{-0.9325978323344497`,-0.3609172801696887`}},{{-0.1653061224489797`,0.5693877551020406`},{0.7743555108383937`,0.6327507746610906`}},{{-0.1653061224489797`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.94796873735714`,0.3183634291081653`}},{{-0.1653061224489797`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.9706202268697152`,0.24061665609716723`}}},{{{-0.01836734693877562`,-0.9`},{0.999329705875488`,-0.0366079083643221`}},{{-0.01836734693877562`,-0.753061224489796`},{0.9991341425188253`,-0.04160487054627046`}},{{-0.01836734693877562`,-0.6061224489795919`},{0.9970265282838748`,-0.07705908056941693`}},{{-0.01836734693877562`,-0.4591836734693878`},{-0.9992645880938419`,0.03834426921515905`}},{{-0.01836734693877562`,-0.31224489795918375`},{0.9999095982712883`,0.01344601371972701`}},{{-0.01836734693877562`,-0.1653061224489797`},{0.9999599814492619`,-0.008946256199771973`}},{{-0.01836734693877562`,-0.01836734693877562`},{0.9999994698138822`,0.0010297436353705167`}},{{-0.01836734693877562`,0.12857142857142845`},{0.9999353371339493`,0.011371963366777916`}},{{-0.01836734693877562`,0.2755102040816325`},{0.9999726292108595`,0.007398704556958564`}},{{-0.01836734693877562`,0.4224489795918366`},{-0.9988671427351832`,-0.04758603959199819`}},{{-0.01836734693877562`,0.5693877551020406`},{-0.3715094436264503`,0.9284291751643554`}},{{-0.01836734693877562`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.999292424080198`,0.03761184887667369`}},{{-0.01836734693877562`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.9996093867892186`,0.027947698346770276`}}},{{{0.12857142857142845`,-0.9`},{0.975404569445539`,0.22042215384294486`}},{{0.12857142857142845`,-0.753061224489796`},{0.9652093789229605`,0.26147821102178403`}},{{0.12857142857142845`,-0.6061224489795919`},{0.9118812502403059`,0.4104541210174126`}},{{0.12857142857142845`,-0.4591836734693878`},{-0.9685135372868642`,-0.24896089671288896`}},{{0.12857142857142845`,-0.31224489795918375`},{0.891154709429378`,-0.45369955241529675`}},{{0.12857142857142845`,-0.1653061224489797`},{0.9991024540989532`,0.04235901572805064`}},{{0.12857142857142845`,-0.01836734693877562`},{0.9999283153189568`,-0.01197348000343983`}},{{0.12857142857142845`,0.12857142857142845`},{0.9972859457442605`,-0.07362569131067999`}},{{0.12857142857142845`,0.2755102040816325`},{0.9998123888784434`,0.019369745614753502`}},{{0.12857142857142845`,0.4224489795918366`},{-0.9532440580196048`,0.3022015318464092`}},{{0.12857142857142845`,0.5693877551020406`},{0.7704704200293884`,-0.6374757500170009`}},{{0.12857142857142845`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.967962799691438`,-0.2510936447095249`}},{{0.12857142857142845`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.98200945560419`,-0.1888317481356417`}}},{{{0.2755102040816325`,-0.9`},{0.8850662521624824`,0.4654650677366212`}},{{0.2755102040816325`,-0.753061224489796`},{0.8482640720103957`,0.5295734737846509`}},{{0.2755102040816325`,-0.6061224489795919`},{0.7401255399325767`,0.6724687242835252`}},{{0.2755102040816325`,-0.4591836734693878`},{-0.9577346502551368`,-0.28765315868363217`}},{{0.2755102040816325`,-0.31224489795918375`},{-0.6640982575452746`,-0.7476453064958877`}},{{0.2755102040816325`,-0.1653061224489797`},{0.9720053620775113`,-0.23495866890277936`}},{{0.2755102040816325`,-0.01836734693877562`},{0.9990805994353862`,-0.042871387099435325`}},{{0.2755102040816325`,0.12857142857142845`},{0.9999068258602314`,0.013650626290283338`}},{{0.2755102040816325`,0.2755102040816325`},{-0.36795283105795334`,0.9298444569477399`}},{{0.2755102040816325`,0.4224489795918366`},{-0.8940288022184032`,0.4480094874039244`}},{{0.2755102040816325`,0.5693877551020406`},{0.7182048244531182`,-0.6958317541850656`}},{{0.2755102040816325`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.8712096925782369`,-0.490911062777907`}},{{0.2755102040816325`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.9255861772780482`,-0.3785369578149664`}}},{{{0.4224489795918366`,-0.9`},{0.7033472078729917`,0.7108464708903511`}},{{0.4224489795918366`,-0.753061224489796`},{0.6641566859942909`,0.7475934031604886`}},{{0.4224489795918366`,-0.6061224489795919`},{0.5278481787944006`,0.8493387428720266`}},{{0.4224489795918366`,-0.4591836734693878`},{0.009009314072353483`,0.9999594153064141`}},{{0.4224489795918366`,-0.31224489795918375`},{-0.81909187847612`,-0.5736623524465078`}},{{0.4224489795918366`,-0.1653061224489797`},{-0.3635992573999994`,-0.9315554626634793`}},{{0.4224489795918366`,-0.01836734693877562`},{0.8073698009628764`,-0.5900457647447063`}},{{0.4224489795918366`,0.12857142857142845`},{-0.1897118078907733`,0.9818398188843304`}},{{0.4224489795918366`,0.2755102040816325`},{-0.7146101027317576`,0.6995229810904763`}},{{0.4224489795918366`,0.4224489795918366`},{-0.18087971132624184`,-0.9835052262344799`}},{{0.4224489795918366`,0.5693877551020406`},{0.5762843989801111`,-0.8172492223869852`}},{{0.4224489795918366`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.7540126592205224`,-0.6568598859233197`}},{{0.4224489795918366`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.8533368067839383`,-0.5213600427610382`}}},{{{0.5693877551020406`,-0.9`},{-0.30777902270273527`,0.9514578672669375`}},{{0.5693877551020406`,-0.753061224489796`},{0.3669712877310585`,0.9302322688345146`}},{{0.5693877551020406`,-0.6061224489795919`},{0.25184835383416787`,0.9677667108714888`}},{{0.5693877551020406`,-0.4591836734693878`},{-0.024135400845369165`,0.9997086987848176`}},{{0.5693877551020406`,-0.31224489795918375`},{-0.5446660265193906`,0.8386530388400071`}},{{0.5693877551020406`,-0.1653061224489797`},{-0.9832662250037523`,0.18217445146581474`}},{{0.5693877551020406`,-0.01836734693877562`},{-0.9923601952817787`,-0.12337440099270973`}},{{0.5693877551020406`,0.12857142857142845`},{-0.9505863282989183`,-0.31046035568359015`}},{{0.5693877551020406`,0.2755102040816325`},{-0.4654138871682305`,-0.8850931666389463`}},{{0.5693877551020406`,0.4224489795918366`},{0.11706002021003604`,-0.9931248419350035`}},{{0.5693877551020406`,0.5693877551020406`},{0.4525267767238453`,-0.8917508151652719`}},{{0.5693877551020406`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.6604850468557957`,-0.7508391990831974`}},{{0.5693877551020406`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.7884436047979527`,-0.6151070492631422`}}},{{{0.7163265306122447`,-0.9`},{-0.8541582131747308`,-0.520013217972535`}},{{0.7163265306122447`,-0.753061224489796`},{-0.7908774137166945`,0.6119746044345242`}},{{0.7163265306122447`,-0.6061224489795919`},{-0.2640825845479232`,0.9645000718188096`}},{{0.7163265306122447`,-0.4591836734693878`},{-0.39131641171973197`,0.9202561958057078`}},{{0.7163265306122447`,-0.31224489795918375`},{-0.6782229270170022`,0.734856218092009`}},{{0.7163265306122447`,-0.1653061224489797`},{-0.9440568132721305`,0.3297828578238562`}},{{0.7163265306122447`,-0.01836734693877562`},{-0.9761104265591787`,-0.2172750219478952`}},{{0.7163265306122447`,0.12857142857142845`},{-0.7167772446022`,-0.6973022168475287`}},{{0.7163265306122447`,0.2755102040816325`},{-0.2963200159189785`,-0.955088712196818`}},{{0.7163265306122447`,0.4224489795918366`},{0.10148142257389554`,-0.9948374343943731`}},{{0.7163265306122447`,0.5693877551020406`},{0.4044957431086684`,-0.9145398809275439`}},{{0.7163265306122447`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.6116051155636105`,-0.7911631833044449`}},{{0.7163265306122447`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.7396282417476892`,-0.6730156491562598`}}},{{{0.8632653061224488`,-0.9`},{-0.7060388918109665`,-0.7081730602404631`}},{{0.8632653061224488`,-0.753061224489796`},{-0.7474415112558233`,-0.6643276204190302`}},{{0.8632653061224488`,-0.6061224489795919`},{-0.9374344194714425`,-0.3481619008309779`}},{{0.8632653061224488`,-0.4591836734693878`},{-0.9966565268541747`,0.08170536995187971`}},{{0.8632653061224488`,-0.31224489795918375`},{-0.9981201090135751`,0.061288236903414`}},{{0.8632653061224488`,-0.1653061224489797`},{-0.9720767334677776`,-0.23466321452374125`}},{{0.8632653061224488`,-0.01836734693877562`},{-0.8004302014230564`,-0.5994259692821504`}},{{0.8632653061224488`,0.12857142857142845`},{-0.49022507731496195`,-0.8715958774406516`}},{{0.8632653061224488`,0.2755102040816325`},{-0.13652038151366105`,-0.9906372622869404`}},{{0.8632653061224488`,0.4224489795918366`},{0.180054574866073`,-0.9836566220332162`}},{{0.8632653061224488`,0.5693877551020406`},{0.4241859154890043`,-0.9055751261495399`}},{{0.8632653061224488`,0.7163265306122447`},{0.5926425726981676`,-0.8054655678709657`}},{{0.8632653061224488`,0.8632653061224488`},{0.6991365809237701`,-0.714988140610892`}}}};


ListVectorPlot[data, 
 VectorColorFunction -> (Hue[ArcTan[#3, #4]/(2 \[Pi])] &), 
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

Comment: See `VectorRange` and `ClippingStyle` in the docs for `ListVectorPlot`. I no longer believe it's a bug.

Comment: I removed the [tag:bugs] tag since the behavior is documented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's clipping (a common problem with density and contour plots). Use `VectorRange -> All`:

```
ListVectorPlot[data, 
 VectorColorFunction -> (Hue[ArcTan[#3, #4]/(2 π)] &), 
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, VectorRange -> All]
```

[image]

So probably not a bug. Since the clipping range is determined automatically, it probably explains the seemingly random behavior discussed in the comments below.

---

*Original answer*

I guess I'd use `Rescale`, but there seems to be a bug:

```
ListVectorPlot[data, 
 VectorColorFunction -> (Hue[
     Rescale[ArcTan[#3, #4], {-Pi, Pi}, {0, 1}]] &), 
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Try postprocessing:

```
ListVectorPlot[data] /. 
 Arrow[p_] :> {Hue[
    Rescale[ArcTan @@ First@Differences[p], {-Pi, Pi}, {0, 1}]], 
   Arrow[p]}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is no matter what formula we use (even `RandomColor[]`), there are vectors that remain gray, and every time, the same vectors.

Comment: @BenIzd Thanks, my poor eyes didn't notice. Interestingly, gray is not a color returned by `Hue` in this plot (according to Reap & Sow). — Is it a bug?

Comment: Yes, that's very interesting. Even if we use a constant color, `GrayLevel[0.85]` appears. More surprising is that if we randomly delete vectors from the dataset, sometimes it works, but a single vector remains gray across many randomly deleted plots! I would consider this a bug.

Comment: `ListVectorPlot[Take[Catenate@data, 39], VectorColorFunction -> (Blue &)]` shows a real magic!

Comment: @BenIzd I guess it's not bug; use `VectorRange -> All`.  See updated answer.

Comment: Yes, indeed it was the `VectorRange`. So much left to learn. The thing I don't understand is in plotting `ListVectorPlot[Take[Catenate@data, 39]]`, we didn't specify anything, and the gray vectors come in but in the first example in the documentation of `VectorRange` it's all colorful although on the 3rd example it shows there are vectors outside the range but it's not gray in that example (the examples are with `VectorPlot`). So I think the question is why `ClippingStyle -> Automatic` in the absence of `VectorColorFunction` behaves differently in `ListVectorPlot` and `VectorPlot`.

Comment: To show the difference, you can try `ListVectorPlot[Table[{x,y}/(Norm[{x,y}]^3+0.001),{x,-1,1,.1},{y,-1,1,.1}]]` with `VectorPlot[{x,y}/Norm[{x,y}]^3,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]`

Comment: @BenIzd In my docs, the second graphics of the table of `{x, y}/Norm[{x, y}]^3` series of examples is wrong. If I reexecute the code, some of the colored vectors show gray ([before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVNSU.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef1h6.png) I assume the colored vector in the center comes from interpolation, say, opposite signs nearly canceling). The first example graphics are wrong, too. — As for why WRI chose a different approach to `ClippingStyle`, Idk, but the docs describe the default behaviors differently. Either it's intentional or an oversight.